# Xamarin C# Transcode .mov to .mp4 with AVAsset Native IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, avasset, avassetexportsession

Problem: Our cross platform application (IOS & Android) cannot play videos on Android that originate from IOS.

Solution: Transcode .mov video files to .mp4 on client IOS applications prior to upload.

Issues: Unable to get the file location on IOS (string input is null). Not sure if my native code / approach is sound.

Exception: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"

Shared Code:

```
try
        {
            MediaPickResult pickresult = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(1, MediaFileType.Video);

            if (pickresult != null)
            {
                foreach (var video in pickresult.Files)
                {
                    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    blobupload.BlobID = guid + ".mp4";
                    string inputfilename = video.NameWithoutExtension + "." + video.Extension;
                    string input = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), inputfilename);
                    string output = Path.Combine(AzureStorage.localpath, guid + ".mp4");

                    if (File.Exists(input))
                    {
                        await IVideoConverter.ConvertVideo(input, output);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Native IOS:

```
public async Task ConvertVideo(string inputpath, string outputpath)
    {
        //string OutputFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(outputpath, "mp4");
        AVAsset asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(inputpath));
        AVAssetExportSession export = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetPassthrough);

        
        export.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(outputpath);
        export.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;
        export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;

        var results = export.DetermineCompatibleFileTypesAsync();
        try
        {
            export.ExportAsynchronously(() =>
            {
                if (export.Error != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(export.Error.LocalizedDescription);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Comment: "Unable to get the file location on IOS" - please describe the **specific** problem including any error messages or exceptions, etc

Comment: I don't know how to get the file location on IOS. In the shared code, the string input is null so I know that line of code is incorrect. https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery/discussions/37

Comment: you are trying to load the file from the app's Personal folder, which is wrong.  I don't believe you can directly access a media gallery video by path (I may be wrong), but you can use the stream to copy the video to a local folder, and then convert that local copy.

Comment: Please move your comment to answer I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest

1. get the stream from the MediaFile
2. write to a local app folder
3. pass the path to that local copy to `ConvertVideo`